# Why is React useState affecting multiple instances of same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have created a component and am using useState to update an area of it where it expands when a button is clicked. When I map multiple instances of this component and click the expand button on one of them, all of them expand. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
const ContainerMenu: React.FC<ContainerMenuProps> = (props: ContainerMenuProps) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`docker-container-menu ${expanded}`}>
                <button onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)} className='chevron-button'>
                    <Icon path={mdiChevronDown} size={1} />
                </button>
                {expanded && <div className='docker-container-menu-expanded'>
                    <button style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => props.startContainer(props.Id)}>
                        <Icon style={{color: "green"}} path={mdiPlay} size={1} />
                    </button>
                    <button style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => props.stopContainer(props.Id)}>
                        <Icon style={{color: "red"}} path={mdiStop} size={1} />
                    </button> 
                </div>}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Edit: I've added the mapping of the component below to show that there are unique keys (the Id prop) being passed through.

```
    return (
        <>
            <div className="app-main-container">
                <div className="docker-containers">
                    {containers.map((container: ContainerProps) => {
                        return (
                            <Container Id={container.Id} State={container.State} Status={container.Status}
                                Names={container.Names} Labels={container.Labels}/>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: When you pass a unique key to a component, it should be specified explicitly with the key attribute `<Container key={container.id} ... />`

Comment: Also, it seems strange that in your mapping the component name is Container, but in your code the component is called ContainerMenu. Are you sure you're using the correct component?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have one State defined and you are using this one state (the same instance,the same time) in all of your expandable buttons.
As we don't see your code for the mapping it could be possible that you have not given an ID to each of the expandable button instances.
Try to map them with a explicit key.

Here is a link to a resource where you can read about the problem:

https://medium.com/geekculture/using-reacts-state-to-update-css-dynamically-c9b45570340c

Comment: I am passing through unique ids via the map method, so I'm not sure why it would still think they're all the same component. I've added the portion of the code containing the mapping of the components.

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved this is by making the btn a separate component and pass the state as prop like this:

```
<ContainerButton onclick={setExpanded(!expanded)} ...props />
```

OK i will show how i do it in my project, the one thing i did not tell you is that i pass a function which has the change state inside it maybe thats the trick:

mapping

```
<div className='pt-4'>
  {CarsModalCardData.map((item, index) => (<CarExpandCard key={index} item={item} />))}
</div>
```

expand component

```
function CarExpandCard({ item }) {
  const [openCarInfo, setOpenCarInfo] = useState(false);

  const setExpandState = () => {
    setOpenCarInfo(!openCarInfo)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='py-2 space-y-1'>
        <div key={item.id} className='w-full p-4 text-xs rounded-lg bg-quaternary'>
          <div className=''>
            <ExpandButton onclick={setExpandState} title={item.car} secondary={item.owner} />

          </div>
          {openCarInfo &&...}
```

Expand button

```
function ExpandButton({ onclick, title, secondary }) {
  
  return (
    <div className='flex items-center justify-between w-full'>
      <div className='flex items-center space-x-1'>
        <div className='flex items-center space-x-2'>

          {secondary &&
            <div className='w-2 h-2 rounded-full bg-blue_custom'></div>
          }
          <h3>{title}</h3>
        </div>
        <h3 className='text-textTertiary'>{secondary}</h3>
      </div>

      <button onClick={onclick} type='button' className={`${!onclick && "rotate-180"} p-2`}>
        <ExpandIcon />
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot and still experienced the same symptom.

Comment: I tried that as well, still didnt work for some reason. I ended up using a classname to expand it in CSS. Not my favorite way to resolve it but it works for now until I can debug it further. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: do you have that code somewhere posted like github?